# deploy adempiere project .war file on jboss server

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x, adempiere

How To deploy **Adempiere** project  .war file on **jboss** server?

Kindly describe the steps briefly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually Adempiere deployment is some what more complicated. You can't find the only one specific .war file in adempiere.

If you are going to do adempiere manually deployment then you need to find the following 
`*.jars and *.wars`  from source and place the jars and wars in respective places in jboss application server

```
 webui.war
 adempiereApps.war
 adempiereRootBase.war
 Adempiere.jar
 AdempiereApps.jar
 AdempiereRoot.jar
 CCTools.jar
 CSTools.jar
 CompiereJasperReqs.jar
```

- Generating the Adempiere Installer :- (You can download adempiere installer from sourceforge also)

  - Adempiere already integrated with jboss 4.2.3. For getting adempiere installers sake you need run the *ADEMPIERE_Trunk/utils_dev/build.xml* using ant. then system will craete installers for you. These installers are available  *ADEMPIERE_Trunk/adempiere/install*.
  - Now copy these installer (.zip or .tar.gz) and place into your desired server location and extract it. Ex :-( C:\Adempiere or /home/user/Adempiere, this path we called as ADEMPIERE_HOME)
- **To Configure Adempiere server** :-
   open up a console window and go to the `$ADEMPIERE_HOME/` directory. Run the script `RUN_setup`(.bat or .sh depending on your OS), Now it will open a popup enter your data (related to database configuration , application server configurations and ports) and click on the OK button. after 1 to 2 Minutes the process will be completed.
- **To Run Adempiere server** :-
  To run the ADempiere Server from a console, open up a console window and go to the `$ADEMPIERE_HOME/utils` directory. Run the script `RUN_Server2` (.bat or .sh depending on your OS).

Now you can access from browser.